# Complex differentiability of $f(z)=|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why is the absolute value function $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z) = |z|$  not complex differentiable at any point $z_0$ in the plane?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: in order to be complex differentiable at a point $p$, it has to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $p$. $f(z) = |z|$ is the same as $f(x+iy) = |x+iy| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So $u(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y) = 0$. Can you see how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't satisfy the Cauchy--Riemann equations

Comment: You got downvoted because you didn't start your answer with "Hint: ".